# join 2 different tables to a third table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have an sql issue. I have 3 tables like in the image. In the front end (User Interface), I have a selectone box to select a course and an employee autocomplete. The autocomplete must retrieve all employee names along with the status for the selected course.

[image]

I tried

```
select e.id,per.id,t.status 
from employee e 
join person per on e.personId=per.id 
left join training t on e.id=t.employeeId`
```

but this retrieves duplicate rows for the employeeId '1'. 
for the employee with id 1, I need to retireve only the row with the selected courseId (selected from User Interface. )

In short,I need all employees information plus the selected courses employee info and also empIds must not repeat.

If selected course id is 34, the retrieved output must contain

```
Empid,PersonName,Status
1, Ravi , 1; 
2, Meera , 0; 
3, Rahul ,0; 
4, Vinu, 0.
```

How do i form the reqd sql query?

As per suggestion provided, I sort of modified the accepted answer to (as per my requirement)

```
SELECT e.id,per.name,COALESCE(t.status,0)
FROM employee e 
JOIN person per ON e.personId=per.id 
LEFT JOIN training t ON e.id=t.employeeId
    AND t.courseId = ?
```

Comment: Replace `left` by `inner`?

Comment: nope, it wont work,
1, Ravi , 0;
1, Ravi , 1; 
2, Meera , 0;

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the where clause on course_id wasn't in the original query, you need that if you want to get the related rows.

Comment: But do you need that info regardless of the employee enrollment in that course?

Comment: yes, i need..beacuse i have show all employee name in an autocomplete suggestion list, and i need to provide css background color for each suggested item based on the status for the selected course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick with left joins is to add the condition on the left-joined table to the *join* condition:

```
select e.id,per.id,t.status 
from employee e 
join person per on e.personId=per.id 
left join training t on e.id=t.employeeId
    and t.courseId = ?
```

This only attempts joins to specific training rows.

If you put the course condition into a *where* clause, you lose the left join - it effectively becomes an inner join, because where clause conditions are executed *after* the join is made. Conditions in the join condition however are executed *as the join is made*.

As a general comment, many people don't realise that you can put non-key conditions into a join condition. In fact, as in this situation, it is the cleanest way to achive the output you want.

Comment: In other words, an extra clause on the join works like a where clause on the second table only.

Comment: yes, i confused as what to do as i cannot possibly put a where clause in my old query.. you have been really helpful..:D